# Proving that $x_i=1/(2+x_{i-1})$ is contractive

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_i)_{i\in \Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence with $x_1 > 0$ and $x_i = (2+x_{i-1})^{-1}$ for $i \geq 2$. Prove that $(x_i)_{i\in \Bbb{N}}$ is a contractive sequence.

I cannot manage to acquire $\vert x_{i+1} - x_i \vert \,\geq \,C\,\vert x_i - x_{i-1}\vert$ for some $C \in [0,1]$.

Comment: contractive means $\leqC$ not $\geqC$

Comment: Hint: $|\frac{1}{2+x} - \frac{1}{2+y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{(2+x)(2+y)} \le \frac14|x-y|$ (for $x, y \ge 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is given by $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ where $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2+x}$.

Now, $|f'(x)|=\dfrac{1}{(2+x)^2} \le \dfrac14 < 1$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Therefore, by the mean value theorem,
$$
|x_{i+1}-x_i| = |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| = |f'(\xi_i)|\,|x_i-x_{i-1}| \le \dfrac14 |x_i-x_{i-1}|
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$.

Your sequence is contractive with $C=\frac{1}{4}$, since

$\forall x>0\;\; |f'(x)|=|\frac{-1}{(x+2)^2}|<\frac{1}{4}$

and by MVT

$(\forall n>0)\;$

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|(x_n-x_{n-1})f'(c)|<\frac{1}{4}|x_n-x_{n-1}|.$$

Let us explain.
we have

1. $x_1>0$
2. $x_2>0$
3. $f$ is decreasing at $(0,+\infty)$
4. $ f(f)$ is increasing.

by induction, we prove that

$\forall n>0\;\; x_{2n-1}>0$ and $x_{2n}>0$

The positive fixe point of $f$, is such

$$\frac{1}{2+L}=L$$

which gives $L=\sqrt{2}-1$.

> Assume that$\;\;0<x_1<L$

then it easy to prove by induction that

$(x_{2n-1})$ increases and $(x_{2n})$ decreases using the fact that $f(f)$ is increasing. thus

$\forall n>0$

$$x_1\leq x_{2n-1}<L<x_{2n}\leq x_2.$$

So, the two sequences $(x_{2n})_n$ and $(x_{2n-1})_n$ are convergent to $L$.

The same approach works if $x_1>L$.

if $x_1=L$, the sequence is constant.